# Add one more option field in the Struts2 select tag

Tags: java, select, struts2, tags

i have one struts 2 select tag like below.

```
<s:select list="myList" listKey="myListVal"  listValue="myListDesc"></s:select>
```

it rendered as below

```
<select data-inputs="myListInput" >
     <option value="myListVal1" >myListDesc1</option>
     <option value="myListVal2" >myListDesc2</option>
     <option value="myListVal3" >myListDesc3</option>
</select>
```

i want to add one more option field with null value

```
<option value="" ></option>
```

to the Option field with modification in the list.

In struts 1 it is possible like below

```
<html:option value=""></html:option>
```

like that is it possible in the struts 2

> **note:i couldn't able to modifiy the list before the page load in the java**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Attribute called `emptyOption` in the select tag.
It worked as below.

```
<s:select list="myList" listKey="myListVal"  listValue="myListDesc" emptyOption="true"  ></s:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add one more option field with null value at the begining of the list you can use `headerKey` & `headerValue` attribute of `s:select` tag.

Check example given below.

```
<s:select list="myList" listKey="myListVal"  listValue="myListDesc"  headerKey="0" headerValue="" ></s:select>
```

So the first element of your list will be empty & it's value will be 0(zero) here.

It will be render as

```
<select data-inputs="myListInput" >
     <option value="" >0</option>
     <option value="myListVal1" >myListDesc1</option>
     <option value="myListVal2" >myListDesc2</option>
     <option value="myListVal3" >myListDesc3</option>
</select>
```

You can set any value on place of 0 (zero).

Hope this will help you.